# How Java determine operating system name?

Tags: java

At the beginning I want to mention that this is not duplicate of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228477/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-operating-system-in-java).

I know that I can check OS I'm running from Java, programmatically via `System.getProperty("os.name");`

My question is: How Java determine my operating system? Other words, when `Properties` are loaded/set (especially `os.name`) and what command is run to do so?

**UPDATE**

Not a duplicate of [Where (which properties file) does System.getProperty(“key”) reads from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396535/where-which-properties-file-does-system-getpropertykey-reads-from) aswell. Im not asking for a place where properties are storaged. Im asking for command that are used to determine OS name.

As @Phylogenesis commented - on Windows it is used a GetVersionEx inside in native c implementation.

What about Unix/Linux?

Comment: Most likely an OS-specific command, issued from the OS-specific implementation of JAVA?

Comment: @TT. Probably. However can I check somewhere what command are used?

Comment: In particular, see the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31909107/javas-os-name-for-windows-10) for more details about how `System.getProperty("os.name")` is generated.

Comment: @ArcticLord I dont think so, Im asking for some kind OS-specific method, not implementation details

Comment: Well that entirely depends on the OS on which JAVA is running on. Each OS has a different function to obtain this information. Java uses JNI to call that OS specific function. So the "command" is different on each OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply have a look into the [OpenJDK source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d).

- **Windows** [src/windows/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/windows/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c)
  line 353: GetVersionEx((OSVERSIONINFO *) &ver);
  more infos about [GetVersionEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/ms724451(v=vs.85).aspx)
- **Linux/Solaris/MacOS** [src/solaris/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/solaris/native/java/lang/java_props_md.c)
  line 504: uname(&name);
  more infos about [uname](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/uname.2.html)