# getting null for default jvm arguments in .conf file

Tags: java, maven, parameters, jvm

im trying to access a property in a .conf file located in the target directory with my jar and its returning null. i followed the spring documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization-conf-file

i believe i should be able to access the properties of the app.conf by simply coding the following:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("dbName"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("dbUser"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("dbPassword"));
```

all three return nulls when i try to run the jar from the terminal. my app.conf file looks like so:

JAVA_OPTS=-DdbName=RandomDb -DdbUser=devUser -DdbPassword=password90210

any recommendations to fix this? i know i can add them to the vm args in the run configs buts i would like to get this to work from a .conf file to avoid exposing sensitive information.

Comment: what OS are we talking about?

Comment: have you tried stringified them? i mean... i guess the space between characters could dificult the proper parsing?... are you sure your jar is named **app.jar**?

Comment: I think this link can help you...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396535/where-which-properties-file-does-system-getpropertykey-reads-from